# Why prove that area is unique?

Tags: calculus, area

in the book Apostol's Calculus Volume 1, in the proof of the area of under of the parabola $x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=b$ it is shown that the area $A$ must satisfy $\frac{b^3}{n^3}(1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2)<A<\frac{b^3}{n^3}(1^2+2^2+...+n^2)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. It is also shown that $\frac{b^3}{3}$ satisfies these inequalities when taken in place of $A$.

Now at this point, I thought to myself: The area of under the parabola from $x=0$ to $x=b$ is clearly unique, so there cannot be two or more values for it. So we *must* automatically have $A=\frac{b^3}{3}$, since  $b^3/3$ satisfies the same inequalities as $A$.

Now Apostol didn't do this. He proceeded to prove that if $A$ satisfies the inequalities, then $A=b^3/3$. I don't see the point of this, it is simply a step that shows that $A$ is unique. I know you have to be rigorous but I don't see how this is rigorous, it just seems almost pointless.

How would you convince someone that it is necessary to continue like Apostol, and show that if $\frac{b^3}{n^3}(1^2+2^2+...+(n-1)^2)<A<\frac{b^3}{n^3}(1^2+2^2+...+n^1)$, then $A=b^3/3$; and why can't this simply be done by the "comparison method" like I did?

I guess this also brings up an important question: Who decides on what is rigorous in maths? What if I said "no, even proving that $A$ is unique isnt enough Apostol, you have to also show that $A$ exists"; would I be correct?

Comment: What we're worried about is not that the area might not be unique, but that our inequalities might not be strong enough to nail it down. For example, one can easily show that the area must satisfy $0 < A < b^3$. Now by your logic, I could say that $b^3/2$ satisfies those inequalities, and the area is clearly unique, so we must have $A = b^3/2$.

Comment: How do you define the area? If it is defined by squeezing as here then you only have a sensible definition if your squeeze operation gives a unique value. How do you know it has a unique value? You have to prove it. (More subtly, you end up having to prove that every similar squeeze operation gives the same result before you have a workable definition of area). Your intuition tells you this is obvious - you have to make sure that your mathematical definition satisfies the obvious properties. And that is not so easy to do for the definition of area/integral - there are plenty of snags.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thanks, I guess it makes sense now (not Rahul's one though because I don't think it really gets to the heart of the problem), you have to prove your geometric intuition about area is true. It's like saying why can't you prove a polynomial has a root by drawing its graph. I think I get it now.

Comment: @user45220: Rahul got to the heart of your specific problem, if not the problem of rigour in general. Consider the following "proof":

We can show that the Queen of England is a woman, by the definition of "Queen". Also, the Queen is clearly unique; there cannot be more than one Queen. When Kate Upton is substituted for the Queen, the property of womanhood holds. Therefore, Kate Upton is the Queen.

Comment: The core of your specific problem is that $b^3/3$ satisfying the same inequalities as $A$ is not sufficient to show that $A=b^3/3$... you must first show that the inequalities have a unique solution. This is a different problem from the given that the area under the parabola is unique.

Comment: @FengyangWang: Thank you, your comment that "this is a different problem..." finally made me understand. So there is the geometric intuition, and the analytic proof. The axiomatic system for calculus is based on reals, not geometry, so we need analytic proofs. Now we can use geometry for intuition, but in a proof only analytical reasoning is good. So in this instance, without the geometric intuition, then as it stands we only have an inequality. Then ignoring the link to area (geometric intuition), we see that there is really no difference between Rahul's example and my problem, (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) except that for my one I know it is lnked to area, but that doesn't have any bearing on the analytic proof. So in the end, I must show that the solution is unique, in order to be rigorous, even though I know what the answer will be (i.e. yes, it is unique). If this is correct, please let me know.

Comment: @user45220: You are mostly correct. The fact that the solution is unique does not imply that any particular method will arrive at a unique solution, only that a sufficiently strong method will arrive at a unique solution. Because it has not been established that Apostol's method is sufficiently strong, Apostol must prove that—by showing that the inequalities indeed arrive at the unique solution $b^3/3$.

Comment: @FengyangWang: Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the area of under the curve is unique but there is the method of calculation of area of under curve. Indeed Apostol want to show that the area is equal to $\frac{b^3}{3}$ on that example.